# ¿Cómo mostrar registros del mes anterior en laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola amigos tengo una consulta, quisiera mostrar registros de un tabla del mes anterior, en mysql lo hago así:

```
SELECT * FROM matriculas WHERE MONTH(fecha_fin) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH));
```

Pero en laravel no tengo idea de como hacerlo, quisiera su ayuda porfavor

Comment: Recuerda es muy importante agregar que llevas al momento, aún cuando no funcione del todo, ¿ya investigaste sobre Carbon?

Comment: Intenta con `$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM matriculas WHERE MONTH(fecha_fin) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH))"));`

Comment: @Sal si usamos [**`DB::select`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-a-select-query) entonces directamente se puede declarar toda la sentencia SQL dentro de dicho método y en consecuencia el método **`DB::raw`** ya no sería necesario